# Is there a command in Linux which waits till it will be terminated?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, terminal, putty

I'm trying to build a Windows batch file, which starts putty/plink with port forwarding, and nothing else.
The Windows part is ready so far:

```
start plink.exe -ssh -i key.ppk -L 1234:localhost:80 sampleUser@192.168.0.1
```

As I don't want to allow to execute other commands after authentication, I'm using `ForceCommand` with a `Match User` declaration:

```
Match User sampleUser
    ForceCommand echo 'Success! Close this window to log out.'
```

Problem is, running my batch file starts putty correctly, but it closes immediately after executing echoing my specified text.

My idea is to use something like this:

```
ForceCommand echo 'Success! Close this window to log out.' && waitTillControlC
```

This way, putty/SSH should keep the connection alive and doesn't quit my port forwarding.

I've thought of commands like `yes`, `ping` or `read`, but they

- are spamming my terminal window
- are actually doing stuff / generating unnecessary CPU load
- could close unexpectedly, if someone presses enter

Is there a command which will do nothing, forever, till somebody terminates it with Ctrl+C or closes the SSH connection by closing the putty window?

What should I use for `waitTillControlC`?

Comment: I found questions like http://superuser.com/questions/587629/putty-run-a-remote-command-after-login-keep-the-shell-running, but they would leave the user with a ready shell.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't get why all the other replies want to use a loop here, sleep is able to wait long enough for any practical purpose and will use no clock cycles doing it.

For example it will try here to sleep for a dubious one hundred years and will likely do it enough to comply with the request anyway:

```
echo "Something"; sleep 36500d
```

Alternatively, this should block too until you type the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key:

```
echo "Something"; read foo
```

Answer (score 9):

Try the `-N` option instead. From the [`plink` documentation](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink):

```
-N        don't start a shell/command (SSH-2 only)
```

This is the same behavior as the `ssh` option `-N`, as described in the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ssh%201):

```
-N      Do not execute a remote command.  This is useful for just for-
         warding ports (protocol version 2 only).
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  The others say how to make a workaround, but this one says how to do it *right*.

Comment: Thanks for the edit; not having a Windows box to check, I didn't think to look for plink docs on-line.

Comment: This answer doesn't fit my needs, because `I don't want to allow to execute other commands after authentication`. `-N` would accomplish this on client-side, so you could just remove -N to execute other commands after authentification.

Answer (score 8):

This should sleep forever without consuming any (noticeable) amount of CPU power.

```
echo "Something" && while true; do sleep 9999; done
```

I'm also not sure whether you can give a command like in the `ForceCommand` clause. You may need to put the command in a shell script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Success! Close this window to log out." && while true; do sleep 9999; done
```

This script should of course be in a place and have permissions such that no ordinary user on the server can write to it.

```
Match User sampleUser
    ForceCommand /usr/bin/waitforever
```

### Edit

I've found a command which seems more elegant:

```
echo "Something" && tail -f /dev/null
```

`tail -f` waits for a file or stream to return bytes. (Otherwise useful for watching logs in realtime.) `/dev/null` will never return bytes. And so the command will sleep forever.

Comment: In this moment, I was trying a sleep loop for myself - yeah, this works definitely!
Even directly with ForceCommand: `ForceCommand echo 'congrats' && while true; do sleep 9999; done`

Comment: `tail -f /dev/null` is technically worse than the 9999 loop. The process will wake up every second instead of every 2 hours and 56 minutes.

Comment: I found it here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42901/how-to-do-nothing-forever-in-an-elegant-way The person answering that question claims "(assuming this uses inotify internally, there should be no polling or wakeups, so other than being odd looking, it should be sufficient)" Is this statement or the assumption that tail uses `inotify` incorrect?

Comment: The assumption is correct, `tail` is optimized to leverage `inotify` when available. This should be the default case with most if not all recent enough distributions. However, I just tested on a Linux laptop and observed spurious activity with `tail` monitoring `/dev/null` so it's certainly worse that sleep in term of clock cycles.

Comment: I do not believe that `tail` will always wake up every second. A possible reason for the result is that you are running it in a terminal which may be communicating with `tail` for whatever reason, whereas `sleep` will not. There is no reason why `tail` should spuriously wake up *just* monitoring `/dev/null`.

Comment: Any number of things will be invoked with `>/dev/null` or similar, and they will cause an inotify-based tail to wake up.

Comment: After trying this, I cannot reproduce any spurious CPU activity at all with the command. Not even when resizing the terminal which I thought might do it. Neither when watching the time column with `top -ppid` or watching the time columns in `/proc/pid/stat`. What are you using to monitor the CPU usage?

Comment: I'm using strace.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try the following:

```
echo "your commands" && while :; do sleep 1; done
```

Comment: For future visitors, you should provide a summary of how this works. Many may know, but you can't assume all will.

Comment: Longer `sleep` period will be easier on the CPU, although even `sleep 1` should be safe enough on anything built in the last two decades...

Comment: `:` is a shorthand for `true`. I would also prefer a longer `sleep` period just out of principle.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to solve this from the wrong end. You don't want the shell not to exit, you want putty to leave the window open.

http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-closeonexit - describes exactly what you need to change. If you want to use the "only on clean exit" option, just add `exit 1` at the end of the ForceCommand.

**Edit:** I misunderstood; you only want to maintain the forwarded ports, you don't want to keep the output of the ForceCommand. In that case, doesn't http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-ssh-noshell do what you want?

Comment: The issue is not that the window closes but that the ssh tunnel is shut down.  Does telling PuTTY to leave the window open also maintain the ssh tunnel?