# Putty - excute remote script and leave console open

Tags: command-line, ssh, putty

I'm running the following command in windows console:

```
"C:\Putty\putty.exe" -load "mySavedSession1" -m C:\somePath\localScript.txt -v
```

localScript.txt content:

```
/somePath/update-new-ver.sh
```

the remote machine is Ubuntu and I want putty to run the remote script.
If I run this `/somePath/update-new-ver.sh` in putty GUI on remote-command box, its working fine, but from windows console it just open and close putty real quick and I cant see if there is an exception thrown.

1. How can I make putty to stay open when done?
2. Am I running this remote script the right way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Putty: run a remote command after login & keep the shell running](http://superuser.com/questions/587629/putty-run-a-remote-command-after-login-keep-the-shell-running)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using putty, i think you can use plink instead. With plink you shouldn't have the problem of the app closing down too quickly on you as this is a console app.

More info here:
http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.53b/htmldoc/Chapter7.html