# Automate putty via batch and execute a command

Tags: batch-file, putty, login, automated-builds

I use `putty` everyday to login to a Linux session and execute some commands.

Now since I have a thought to automate this process, I would like some help to complete this process.

I have made a batch file which contains the below commands:

```
Start putty.exe abc@1.1.1.1 22 -pw 1234
```

Using this script I am able to open a `putty` session.

Now I want it execute my next command as well:

```
ps -eaf|grp sometext
```

Can you please help me to achieve this?

It's a huge challenge for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PuTTY: Run a remote command after login & keep the shell running](http://superuser.com/questions/587629/putty-run-a-remote-command-after-login-keep-the-shell-running)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can call another script inside this existing batch file containing further commands that you want to execute .

I just had a look at this , just something similar to what you are trying :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439039/batch-file-for-putty-psftp-file-transfer-automation

Answer (score 0):

You should use a server-login script. On your server, create a `.bash_profile`-file in your home folder (if it isn't already present) and put in the scripts there. Usually your server is set up to run the `.bash_profile` login script every time the user logs in.

To get to know where your home folder is, type `echo $HOME`.

Maybe you also want to set up SSH, so that you don't have login each time. I'm not sure how *secure* it is to pass login-credentials through the batch-file.

Comment: That would cause the script to run on every log in , and even any time a new shell is started (via `screen`, local login, etc).  If this is a daily task, why not just set a cron  job on the remote machine itself to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at PuTTY's Plink command?

Quoting from the documentation:

> Plink is a command-line connection tool similar to UNIX ssh. It is mostly used for automated operations, such as making CVS access a repository on a remote server.

https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.70/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink

Comment: This suggestion looks promising, but have *you* looked at it?   We prefer answers that are answers, not just suggestions.   Can you explain how the OP can use `plink` to solve his problem?   Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.