# Automated PuTTY session load and commands

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, putty

I want to be able to automatically run PuTTY, connect to a server and then run a number of commands. For example in my local development environment I use PuTTY to run a Rails server so the process usually entails me opening PuTTY , loading a saved session which uses SSH authentication key. I then open the session enter the password and then run the following commands:

```
cd /vagrant
RAILS_ENV='development' bundle exec rails s
```

I have seen suggestions for using `.bat` files however I was hoping for an approach which means for every session opened I do not have a command prompt window open also.

Comment: Possibly answered [here](http://superuser.com/questions/587629/putty-run-a-remote-command-after-login-keep-the-shell-running).

Comment: Thanks! Will post my solution when I get it done. Think I seen this question but wasnt sure it was the right approach for me.

Answer (score 0):

Save a putty profile with the remote commands. This is the gui equivelant of the -m option.

`Remote command`option in putty configuration: `Connection > SSH`

[image: putty Configuration]

When you say "automatically run putty". There must be a trigger to automatically open this putty profile. I used to use autohotkey, then started using shortcut files in an "aliases" folder which is in my $PATH variable. A shortcut may look something like this in the Target: field `"C:\path_to_putty\putty.exe -load profilename`